# Is there a way to reliably and rapidly send information through a TCP network?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, video-streaming

I'm sorta trying to create code that allows for "streaming" in java, and I decided to do it with sockets as it felt convenient. The idea was: The server class initializes a ServerSocket set to a unused port number, and starts a while(true) loop, with these as contents:

```
Socket connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();
OutputStreamWriter outToClient = new OutputStreamWriter(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
Robot r = null;
try {
    r = new Robot();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// Takes the screenshot
Rectangle capture = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
BufferedImage image = r.createScreenCapture(capture);
// Sends the screenshot
ImageIO.write(image, "png", connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
outToClient.flush();
```

The client has a simple gui for me to see the image update, and runs this while(true) loop:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("MY IP ADDRESS", 903);
imgToDraw = ImageIO.read(socket.getInputStream());
socket.close();
repaint(); // re-paints the gui to show update
```

When I tested this server-client model on my own machine, it was extremely stutter-y and constantly lagging. I tested the screen-recorder **without** the socket sending information, and that worked fine, so I figured it was probably a problem with this line
`Socket connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();` constantly blocking the code (I would like to say there is a high possibility I am completely wrong). Is there a way to make this more efficient and run as intended (screen-sharing code)?

Apologies for my ignorance, and thanks for your time!

Comment: Data transfer adds significant overhead no matter what design is used. While your design of having a new TCP connection for each data transfer is far from optimal (use a single TCP connection instead for multiple frames) the main problem is likely that you transfer too much data. Remote desktop applications don't send uncompressed frames but instead compress the information a lot and also only send differences between consecutive frames since not much has changed. This way the amount of transferred data is vastly lower, which means increased performance and less latency.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Not gonna lie, a little discouraged after reading that, since I have no clue how to implement compressed information just yet. With that said, how would you recommend creating a single TCP connection to use repeatedly? I figured I should probably drop a few lines out of the while(true) loop, but I couldn't get it to work without a socket exception popping up.

Comment: *"how would you recommend creating a single TCP connection to use repeatedly?"* - single accept then do many reads. You need some kind of message semantics so that you know when one frame ends and the next one starts. Often this is done by having fixed length prefix for the length of the message  followed by the message itself. Note that there are many similar questions here, both about multiple messages with TCP and for the kind of application and for implementing some kind of remote desktop.